# Confusing function in javascript functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and I'm trying to learn it in javascript.  I found some examples and wrote my own snippet, but I don't understand WHY it works.  There is a function called whatTheHeckIsThis.  Can someone tell me what it is doing or what its purpose is?  Note that when running this code, the output is true.

```
function boolFlipper(someFn){
    return function whatTheHeckIsThis(x,y){
        return !someFn(x,y);
    };
}

var checkStrings = function(x, y){
    return x === y;
}

var flipperTester = boolFlipper(checkStrings);

var str1 = "this string";
var str2 = "that string";

console.log(flipperTester(str1, str2));
```

My confusion is why can't I just do this instead:

```
function boolFlipper(someFn){ 
    return !someFn(x,y); 
}
```

Comment: So apart from the unnecessary expletives, which bit is confusing you?

Comment: Do you know what `!` does? If you know the basics of functional programming, then it should be obvious how this affects the function.

Comment: I think my question is why can't I just do this instead:


function boolFlipper(someFn){
    return !someFn(x,y);
}

Comment: Because that doesn't return a new function, it just calls the function once. That's the essence of higher-order function programming.

Comment: @Accribus Where do `x` and `y` come from in that function?

Comment: @Barmar That is part of my question.  I got this snippet to work based on other code I've seen.  But I don't get why it works.  I'm passing values to flipperTester but how does the checkStrings function get access to them?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1.

Comment: @Accribus You're calling `someFn` with the values, and `someFn` is the `checkStrings` function you passed in to create the `flippedTester`.

Answer (score 1):

a reference to `whatTheHeckIsthis()` will be returned and stored into `flipperTester`

After this, `flipperTester` can be used like a function.

You can use this language feature to abstract some code.

Simple example:

```
function addTen(x) { return x + 10 }
function multiplyByTen(x) { return x * 10 }

...

var doMath

// somewhere a user selected something
if (userInputSaysAdd) doMath = addTen
if (userInputSaysMultiply) doMath = multiplyByTen

// this will be the choosen function
doMath(someValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second version doesn't work for 2 reasons:

1. The purpose of `boolFlipper` is to return a new function, which you can assign to another variable and later call.
2. Your function doesn't have `x` and `y` parameters.

To solve #2 you could write:

```
function boolFlipper(someFn, x, y) {
    return !someFn(x, y);
}
```

You would then have to call it like:

```
console.log(boolFlipper(checkStrings, str1, str2));
```

But you still couldn't do:

```
flipperTester = boolFlipper(checkStrings);
```

The original snippet returns a closure, which is bound in the environment where `someFn` is equal to the function passed as an argument to `bookFlipper()`. You can then assign this function to a variable, and call it with new arguments, that are assigned to `x` and `y`, and then the the function saved in `someFn()` is called, the return value is negated with `!`, and this is returned.

For more information about closures, see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are objects, so you can return them. When you return a function you are getting a function object, so you can call it as any other function. For example:

```
function myFun() {
    return function() {
        console.log("test");
    };
}

var functionInside = myFun();
/* This is like doing:
var functionInside = function() {
    console.log("test");
};
*/

functionInside(); // This will execute the function.
```

---

Example with your code:

This variable:

```
var flipperTester = boolFlipper(checkStrings);
```

contains a function like this:

```
var flipperTester = function (x,y) {
    return !someFn(x,y);
}
```

And this is something similar to

```
function flipperTester(x,y) {
    return !someFn(x,y);
}
```

So when you do:

```
flipperTester(str1, str2)
```

You are executing that function. The variable "someFn" inside there is the function "checkStrings", because you passed it when you initialize flipperTester variable.

Comment: I'm following this example, but I'm confused about how the parameters being passed in are utilized in my example.  Like @Barmar was asking... where do the X and Y come from?  I know I pass them into flipperTester, but I don't see how the whatTheHeckIsThis function gets them.

Answer (score -1):

`boolFlipper` is, for our purposes here, a function *decorator*: it takes a function and modifies it to do something else. A more instructive example might be a logging function:

```
var alsoLogs = f => (...args) => {
  var result = f(...args);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};

// now we have a function that adds 2 numbers:
var add = function add(a, b) { return a + b; };

// and we want to also log the result
var addAndLog = alsoLogs(add); // addAndLog is a function, would be the whatTheHeckIsThis from your example
addAndLog(2, 3); // logs 5 to the console
```

If you don't understand all the ES6 syntax that's ok, just understand that `alsoLogs` take a function f and returns a function that does the exact same thing as f but also logs the result to the console.

Since we as programmers are lazy, we don't want to have to write functions to glue together other functions every time we want to do this, so we write a function to do it for us, [compose](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose).

So now we can just say something like:

```
var addAndLog = R.compose(console.log, add);
addAndLog(2, 3); // logs 5 to the console
```